# Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for "region"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform, apologies for asking such a basic question. I am trying to create an s3 bucket resource using terraform. Below is my code,

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_very_first_bucket" { 
  bucket = "hetal-s3-my-very-first-bucket" 
  region = "ap-south-1"
}
```

The command `terraform init` was executed successfully but I am getting below error while executing `terraform apply`.

```
C:\Users\Hetal Rachh\IdeaProjects\demo>terraform apply
provider.aws.region
  The region where AWS operations will take place. Examples
  are us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.

  Enter a value: ap-south-1

╷
│ Error: Computed attributes cannot be set
│
│   on s3.tf line 3, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_very_first_bucket":
│    3:   region = "ap-south-1"
│
│ Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for "region".
╵
```

May I know what am I doing wrong here? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a variable defined for region? Do you have a `variables.tf` file in the same directory or something similar?

Comment: No I have not defined anything like that @MarkoE

Comment: This is all the code you have? If not, please paste everything (edit the question), just be careful to omit any sensitive info if there is something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because AWS provider does not use `region` for the S3 resource. However, S3 provides an attribute with the same name after it is created successfully. The question you are getting is probably because you have not set any provider related configuration. What you could do is add the following at the top of the `s3.tf` file:

```
provider aws {
  region = "ap-south-1"
}
```

For the S3 bucket, you would then have:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_very_first_bucket" { 
  bucket = "hetal-s3-my-very-first-bucket" 
}
```

Here is the Terraform provider documentation for S3: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket. At the bottom, see the exported attributes for S3: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#attributes-reference.

Comment: What does it mean by "exported attributes"?

Comment: Each resource created with any of the Terraform providers will provide you with a set of attributes that can be queried *after* a resource is created. In the case of an S3 bucket, the second URL shows all the attributes that will be available for you to use. This enables you to keep the code DRY and reference values from the already created resources as values for configuring other resources. Here's a more detailed explanation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html#references-to-resource-attributes.

Comment: This answer worked for me as well. Thank you for providing this information.